# Extract substring between a word and a character

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Trying to extract substring between word 'by' and character '.', but don't want to include either 'by' or '.' in the result.  I've tried several versions of substring and patindex that I found on this site, but can't quite get the desired result.  Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

sample data:  12:31 PM by Smith, Jim.
desired result: Smith, Jim

Comment: you should post your attempts that you have already tried. Please show this effort. It is also a good starting point to be able to help you

Comment: Yes, especially because otherwise people might post the things you already tried and don't like, then they'll be wasting their time doing so.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  What I tried didn't work, so I thought it would just lead to confusion.  I'll be sure to include this in the future, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is possible solution, that will suite most of the cases. Have a look:

```
select
substring(s,CHARINDEX(s1,s)+len(s1)+1,charindex(s2,s)-len(s2)-(CHARINDEX(s1,s)+len(s1)))
from (
    select
    '12:31 PM by Smith, Jim.' as s,
    'by' as s1,
    '.' as s2
) as a
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm receiving an invalid length parameter error, when I plug in my actually tables.                                                                                                                                            select substring(s,CHARINDEX(s1,s)+len(s1)+1,charindex(s2,s)-len(s2)-(CHARINDEX(s1,s)+len(s1)))
from 
(select oc.commenttext as s,
'by' as s1,
'.' as s2
from copia.copia_sf.OrderedPanelComment oc
where oc.createstamp > 1510434000000) as a

Comment: That might be the case if there is no such substring as 'by' or '.'. You need additional filter in WHERE or some logic with CASE expression. Hard to say without seeing all the data.

Comment: Thanks for the input and patience with beginners.  You are exactly right, I filtered my comments to only include those with the specific substring I'm interested in.  It is now returning the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I want to use charindex for this, so I replaced the word 'by' with ascii value 6, which shouldn't be something you can type with the keyboard.

```
DECLARE @newstring varchar(100) = (SELECT REPLACE('12:31 PM by Smith, Jim.', 'by', char(6)))

SELECT SUBSTRING( @newstring
                , CHARINDEX(CHAR(6), @newstring) + 1
                , CHARINDEX('.', @newstring) - CHARINDEX(CHAR(6), @newstring) - 1
                )
```

Gives output:

```
Smith, Jim
```